# Pandas - determine if dates are within multiple start stop ranges by user

Tags: python, pandas, date

I have a dataframe of start and stop dates for multiple users. There may be duplicate starts before a stop, stops before another start, or there may never be a stop date. An "active period" is defined as one between the start and stop dates (inclusive of endpoints), where a duplicate start or stop has no effect.

[image: Start/stop dates]

I then have a second dataframe of user login dates.

[image: Login dates]

I would like to determine by member and month whether or not the member had an "active period" during that month in which they also had a login action. The active period does not need to cover the entire month. So the desired result is:

[image: Desired Result]

I have been playing around with resampling and also thought using `pd.Grouper(key='date_col', freq='M')` might be useful but I can't quite put it all together.

Code to reproduce sample dataframes is below.

```
import pandas as pd

person_id = [1,1,1,1,2,2]
action_date = pd.to_datetime(
['2019-01-01', '2019-01-05', '2019-02-15', 
 '2019-04-05', '2019-02-14', '2019-04-07'])
action = ['start', 'start', 'stop', 'start', 'start', 'stop']

action_df = pd.DataFrame( 
    {'person_id': person_id, 'action_date': action_date, 'action': action} 
)


login_person_id = [1,1,1,1,2,2]
login_date = pd.to_datetime(
    ['2019-01-03', '2019-01-04', '2019-02-18', '2019-03-15', '2019-01-02', '2019-03-19'])
login_df = pd.DataFrame({'person_id': login_person_id, 'login_date': login_date})
```